# Rational representation of a 136 order group

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let G be the group of order 136 = 8 * 17 with presentation $$<x,y : y^{8}=x^{17}=1 \quad yxy^{-1}=x^{4} >$$
Find the simple summands of the group ring Q[G].

Comment: Just like that? Not a little "please", "if you don't mind"...something? More important: this is *not* basic group theory, so what have you tried? Where's your self effort?

Comment: @DonAntonio I am sorry, the original problem has 3 questions， the first two are (a) Find the center of G.
(b) Describe the number and dimensions of the irreducible complex representations of
G. I think they are easy to solve out so I do not mention them at all